# How to detect if Jquery syntax highlighting is applicable to a source file

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-highlighting

I'm implementing a script to detect if jQuery is being used within a JavaScript source file (for a sublime text plugin).

Right now (aside from the obvious JavaScript extension test) my solution checks if any of the following substrings appears within the file:

```
jquery_idioms = [
    '$(function',
    '$(document)',
    '$(window)',
    '$(this)'
    '$.fn',
    '$.ajax',
    '$.noConflict',
    'jQuery.noConflict'
]
```

I don't think that 100% certanity is achievable (because of similar libraries using replicating jQuery's API, etc), but I'm trying to build a good list of substrings that avoids most false positives.

As I am not a huge jQuery expert, the question is:

Am I missing any very often used jQuery idioms?

PS: (I don't think it's possible but) Alternative non substring searching ideas?

Comment: @RicardoLohmann That does the same as `$(function`, doesn't it? And I have the `noConflict` to try to cover when `'$'`  is not being used.

Comment: `(jQuery)` is found at the end of most well written plugins, in the form of `(function($){ ... plugin code ... })(jQuery)` this would also still be there after minification, where as many of the ones you listed would be hidden/changed after being minified.

Comment: @KevinB ok, thank you for your suggestion. I'm not really worried about the minification. It's for an editor plugin so I expect code written manually.